# Add values to PS object from other PS command

Tags: powershell

I created the following object:

```
$PSOhash = @{
    ConnectedNode = $ConnectedNode
    ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber = $ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber
    Serialnumber = $Serialnumber
    ProductId = $ProductId
    }
$ClusterNodeSSDs =  New-Object PSObject -Property $PSOhash
```

and want to add values from the following command into it:

```
$SSDModel = "xyz123" 
$ClusterNode = "Node1"
gwmi -Namespace root\wmi ClusPortDeviceInformation| select ConnectedNode,ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber, Serialnumber, ProductId | sort ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber | where {($_.ConnectedNode -eq $ClusterNode) -and ($_.ProductId -match "$SSDModel")}
```

which returns the proper informations, but need them as properties in the object for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a set of property-value pairs to an already existing PSObject (`$MyObject` in this example) ***that currently does not have those properties***, you can use the [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6) command for this:

```
$PSOhash = @{
    ConnectedNode = $ConnectedNode
    ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber = $ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber
    Serialnumber = $Serialnumber
    ProductId = $ProductId
    }
$MyObject = $MyObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $PSOHash
```

**Explanation:**

The `-NotePropertyMembers` parameter allows you do add a hash table of property-value pairs to a custom object.

Optionally, you can use a combination of `Add-Member`'s `-NotePropertyValue` and `-NotePropertyName` to add properties one at a time.

---

If you want to update one object's property values with property values (same property names) from another object, you can just use direct assignment and the member access operator (`.`).

```
$SSDModel = "xyz123" 
$ClusterNode = "Node1"
$WmiObjects = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi ClusPortDeviceInformation |
    Select-Object ConnectedNode,ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber, Serialnumber, ProductId |
        Sort-Object ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber |
            where {($_.ConnectedNode -eq $ClusterNode) -and ($_.ProductId -match "$SSDModel")}

$ClusterNodeSSDs = foreach ($WmiObject in $WmiObjects) {
    $PSOhash = @{
        ConnectedNode = $WmiObject.ConnectedNode
        ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber = $WmiObject.ConnectedNodeDeviceNumber
        Serialnumber = $WmiObject.Serialnumber
        ProductId = $WmiObject.ProductId
    }
    [pscustomobject]$PSOhash
}
```

**Explanation:**

Note the use of the `foreach` loop here because the `Get-WmiObject` will likely return a collection. So you will need to iterate all of them to create custom objects. However, it just seems that you can just use the `Get-WmiObject | Select-Object` output to perform the same thing.

Comment: changed ($WmiObject in $WmiObject) into ($WmiObject in $WmiObjects) and added } on the end. This helped me finishing the script.